# Identifying difference of rows with a similar column using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have written a script to parse a csv file. The csv file contains an ID and timestamp.

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names = ['ID','TSTAMP','DIFF'], delimiter=';')
d = {'min':'TSTAMP-INIT','max':'TSTAMP-FIN'}
df = df.groupby(['UID'])['TSTAMP'].agg([min, max]).reset_index().rename(columns=d)
df['DIFF'] = (df['TSTAMP-FIN'] - df['TSTAMP-INIT'])
```

If you think about this as the csv file (the dots indicate other elements in the series)

```
    3w]{;1495714405280
...
    3w]{;1495714405340
...
    3w]{;1495714571213
...
    3w]{;1495714571317
...
    3w]{;1495714405280
...
    3w]{;1495714405340
...
    3w]{;1495714571213
...
    3w]{;1495714571317
```

the df gives me output as the difference between the first and last occurrence of `3w]{`

```
    UID   DIFF
0  3w]{   166037
```

Instead when I want the output to be the difference of consecutive ID's.

```
     UID    DIFF
0    3w]{   60
1    3w]{   104
...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

on the UID column you are aggregating timestamp and then picking up min and max for that uid and then taking the difference. but for your requirement select the two columns and then rank them and do a self join on it with uid and rank = rank-1. or you can apply Rolling() pandas method.

Comment: can you provide an MWE?

Comment: providing an MWE as in (i am new to SO)?